# Sql job step queries run in parallel or sequentially?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple question, inside a sql job step I have many selects. Do they execute in parallel or sequentially?

The job step I am analyzing in question is something like:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE FinalTable1
INSERT INTO FinalTable1
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.TableAux1 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tableAux2 ON dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table2.ID
WHERE  dbo.TableAux1.Name IS NULL


TRUNCATE TABLE FinalTable2
INSERT INTO FinalTable2
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.ViewTable1 
       INNER JOIN dbo.TableAux1 ON dbo.ViewTable1.ID = dbo.TableAux1.ID


TRUNCATE TABLE FinalTable3
INSERT INTO FinalTable3
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.ViewTable2 
      INNER JOIN dbo.TableAux1 ON dbo.ViewTable2.ID = dbo.TableAux1.ID
```

The job step takes too long to execute.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server (including clients like SQL Agent) execute statements in a batch sequentially. If you have many statements, add `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: If you have Integration Services, you can paralellesize each step and then only run one package. Which will make your step faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code inside 1 step is executed sequentially.

All the steps within a job are executed sequentially.

You can use `SSIS` to create a package where put your INSERTS to be executed in parallel.

To speed up your `INSERTS`, use `TABLOCK` hint to achieve minimal logging.